# android horizontalscrollview children: one per page

Tags: android, android-studio, horizontalscrollview

I have this portion of file `activity_main.xml` that I want to let the horizontalscrollview children be 100% width as the picture shows.

[image: not 100%]

here's my `activity_main.xml`

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:layout_marginBottom="-150dp"
android:id="@+id/bottom_menu">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:background="#66eeff" android:id="@+id/bottom_scroll"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/optionpage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/optionpage"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/settings2"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_button"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_menu_button" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:id="@+id/testo"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

that produces this children size (the image view width)
 [image: 100%]

as the xml shows, I have multiple images to being displayed horizontally and let the users scroll "pages".

how can I edit my activity_main.xml file in order to let the children be displayed full width?

Comment: Can't you  use ViewPager instead?

Comment: ok, I could solve my problem using viewpager, but I just want to make my code works.